# ArrayList.Indexof("Value") returns -1

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-spinner

I am using `ArrayList.Indexof("Value")` in one of my Application. `ArrayList` contains 400+ values and I am using this List to show in spinner. I want to move spinner on a particular position for that I need the `Indexof` that Item. I am using Spinner's `setSelection` but here `ArrayList.Indexof("Value")` returns -1... Why??? Please help me..

Comment: post your code to identify as of what mistake you are making.

Comment: Your ArrayList is of what type?, Plucury is right

Comment: C'mon Krisjnakant - you **know** that you can't ask a question like this without showing us the code.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/Vsexpressvcs/thread/ef310e77-b6ce-4685-8e50-3cf76f26de33

Answer (score 6):

See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29):

It returns -1 if there is no such index

Comment: But search value exist in Arraylist

Comment: @KrishnakantDalal Looks like it does not. Have you tried debugging your code? Is it using the same case ("value" vs. "Value")?

Comment: @KrishnakantDalal Obviously not. Otherwise it wouldn't return -1, would it.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that it returns -1 tells you that no index "Value" is present in the ArrayList. To compare, `equals()` is used. Two points where it could fail:

- spelling, including case ("value".equals("Value") -> false)
- Your ArrayList does not contain Strings but something else which then might use a different implementation than `String#equals(String)`

If you want us to be able to give you more information, we need some code...

Answer (score 0):

> I am using Spinner's setSelection but here ArrayList.Indexof("Value") returns -1

This tells you that the string is in fact not in the list.  Period.

So what could *really* be going on?

@brimborium has identified a couple of possibilities:

- the value in the list and the value that you are testing differ in case
- the value in the list or the value that you are testing is not a String

And some others are:

- one or other of the values has leading or trailing whitespace that doesn't show up
- certain Unicode codepoints (characters) look the same when rendered but are different, and compare as different

Or ... your code either didn't add the value, or it removed it.